# Is there a way to make an email link work on desktop?

Tags: html, html-email

I have achieved creating an email link that works on mobile devices using 'href="mailto:example@webki.com"' When you click on the button via mobile device, it prompts you asking how you want the email delivered however when I click on it from google chrome on my lap top it does nothing. Does any one have a solution that would work on desktops as well? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: `mailto` does work on desktops. It opens your default mail app(outlook, for example) `Compose` window with `To` set to 'example@webki.com'

Comment: The `mailto` functionality is the same on a desktop as it is on a mobile device.  The problem you're *probably* facing is that a lot of desktops don't have local email clients.  They used to, but webmail became popular a decade or so ago and has been pretty dominant ever since.

Comment: @David so the only way to do it would be to work with gmail, yahoo, etc's api? Like how craigslist has options to reply via a bunch of different email suppliers and opens their window in the browser.

Comment: @user3145782: That seems like a losing battle, since you'd have to continue to support many APIs over time and even then wouldn't cover everyone.  If you have a web application which needs to send an email, I recommend building a form on that web application which accepts the inputs of an email (subject, body, from address, etc.) and then use server-side code to send the actual email through your own email provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That work on desktop well. I think on your laptop not configured e-mail client by default. On my laptop when I click on link with "mailto:" opened browser with gmail

Answer (score 2):

Using something like:

```
<a href="mailto:example@webki.com">send mail</a>
```

must work both in mobile and desktop.

Comment: check out my website gulfstate.us go to the bottom and you will find a mail icon, click it and see if it works. I have it set up as you wrote above but it only responds on my mobile.

Comment: I tried it and works fine for me and for everybody with a default email client configured.

Answer (score 0):

`mailto` works both on mobiles and desktops.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The `To` attribute is not the only one that you can pre-set using mailto though. You can also have CC, BCC, Subject, Body...something like:

`mailto:example@webki.com?cc=thisguy@thatsite.com, thatguy@thissite.com&bcc=someguy@mysite.com&subject=Happy%20New%20Year&body=Howdy`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/55P6s/)